# Toggle auto close

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following js code:
This code is used on a FAQ toggle page.

It works basically as every toogle code, but I would like to add the auto-close function when clicking to an other question.

Hide the prev question content, then show the next one.
Any ideas?

```
if ( 'function' !== typeof(window[ 'vc_toggleBehaviour' ] ) ) {
window.vc_toggleBehaviour = function ( $el ) {
    function event( e ) {
        e && e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault();
        var title = jQuery( this );
        var element = title.closest( '.vc_toggle' );
        var content = element.find( '.vc_toggle_content' );
        if ( element.hasClass( 'vc_toggle_active' ) ) {
            content.slideUp( {
                duration: 300,
                complete: function () {
                    element.removeClass( 'vc_toggle_active' );
                }
            } );
        } else {
            content.slideDown( {
                duration: 300,
                complete: function () {
                    element.addClass( 'vc_toggle_active' );
                }
            } );
        }
    }

    if ( $el ) {
        if ( $el.hasClass( 'vc_toggle_title' ) ) {
            $el.unbind( 'click' ).click( event );
        } else {
            $el.find( ".vc_toggle_title" ).unbind( 'click' ).click( event );
        }
    } else {
        jQuery( ".vc_toggle_title" ).unbind( 'click' ).on( 'click', event );
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever any of the questions are clicked, if you were to hide all active questions you won't have to worry about which one -if any- are currently active.

(on question click):

```
$('.vc_toggle_active').each(function(){
    $(this)slideUp( {
        duration: 300,
        complete: function () {
            $(this).removeClass( 'vc_toggle_active' );
        }
    });
});
```

After sliding up any currently active question, go ahead and show the clicked one.

NB. Code not tested, since you have no fiddle and no html. Hope you get the concept though.

Comment: Ye i understood the concept, but im still missing something, because i tryed to modify that file with changes that u suggested but still not workin... this is my html code for 1 question.

Comment: <div id="1448479424457-14565b23-c0a2" class="vc_toggle vc_toggle_default vc_toggle_color_default  vc_toggle_size_md">
 <div class="vc_toggle_title"><h4>¿Cuál es tu estilo?</h4><i class="vc_toggle_icon"></i></div>
 <div class="vc_toggle_content"><p class="Standard">this is text .</p>
</div>
 </div>

Comment: I am sorry it's not working. The code I wrote would need to be associated with the click event of all questions. It's not likely to work if you just copy it into some region of your existing code.
Base line is: Just close all questions whenever one is clicked, that way you won't have to keep track on which one is currently active.